# Constraint on the same row

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

If there is possible insert of the same row in table I want to ignore this one. Here the table with foreign key game_id and 2 fields step_num and cell, they could differ and should differ. Cell should be 0-8 and always different for game_id. Step_num the same, but 1-9. But I can't set unique, because the could be the same, but in different game_id's. 

**Here is part of the script:**

```
create table games(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null unique ,
    status varchar(255) not null,
    createDate DATETIME
);

create table steps(
    game_id int not null ,
    step_num int not null,
    cell int not null,
    constraint cell_unique on games(id),
    constraint chk_number check(step_number > 0 and step_number < 10),
    constraint fk_game foreign key (game_id) references games(id) on delete cascade,
    constraint chk_cell check(cell >= 0 and cell <= 8)
);
```

INSERT IGNORE didn't worked adn INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY I think not what I need. If I try Insert (2, 2, 2) several times, it should ignore. I prevent this actions on the back-end side, but want, that db was correct and automatically prevent from similar actions.

**What are the ways to do it correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Define composite primary key using `( game_id, step_num, cell )`. This restricts repeated row data like `2, 2, 2`.
2. Define a `before insert trigger` that checks duplicates and 
    to restrict, updates the same row with same values, affecting no rows.

And as per my knowledge `check` constraints have no effect in `MySQL`.